# Spike Filtering in Real time C++

Tags: c++, filter, real-time, spike

I'm trying to implement a spike filter on some torque that I'm reading in from an SEA in real time. As of now, we're using a moving average to replace the spike values that cross a certain threshold. (We're getting spikes b/c the actuator sometimes messes up and gives a sudden spike).

I am trying to figure out a better, more accurate way to filter the spikes, so that it more accurately predicts what the torque would have been instead of the spike.

BTW, this is a c++ program.

Thanks!

Comment: Research "exponential filter c++".  We are using a kind of exponential filter for filtering voltage spikes.

Answer (score 0):

If your torque isn't changing very fast the easiest way to filter spikes is so-called "slew rate limiter". The operation is trivial and can easily be implemented in any language. You need to store last good value. When you get a reading compare it with the last and if it's larger then increment last one, if it's smaller then decrement the last one.